# Pentaho / Salesforce: How to integrate SF-Enterprise-Web-Services-API V48.0 into PDI 9.0 that only supports v47.0

Tags: web-services, salesforce, pentaho, kettle, pdi

actually I am working with PDI 8.2, however I am able to upgrade to 9.0.

The main issue is that a customer wants to pull data from salesforce which works well so far. But he is using the Enterprise Web Services API with version 48.0, latest Pentaho supports v47.0 only.

I strongly assume that reading via v48.0 won't work with PDI so that I have to build a workaround. 
Could anyone point me to a feasible solution?
 To be honest, I don't even know whether the Enterprise or the Partner API is relevant for Pentaho. Have got my own SF-Account so that I could try around with the APIs.
Is the "Web Services lookup" the right step for the workaround?

Any answer would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, what a crazy question, all over the place.

> I strongly assume that reading via v48.0 won't work

You'd have to try it but it should work. Salesforce has 3 releases a year and that's when they upgrade API versions. We're in Spring'20 now, it's v.48. That doesn't mean anything below is deprecated. You should have no problems calling with any API version >= 20. From what I remember their master service agreement states that API version released will stay up at least 3 years. Well, v.20 is 9 years old and still going strong...

Check for example https://baa.my.salesforce.com/services/data/ (if your client has "My Domain" enabled you can use that too instead of some unknown company), you should see a list similar to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_versions.htm (no login required, that'd be a chicken & egg situation. You need to choose API version you want when making the login call).

So... what does your integration do. I assume it reads or writes to SF tables (objects), pretty basic stuff. In that sense the 47 vs 48 won't matter much. You should still see Accounts, Contacts, custom objects... You won't see tables created specifically in v 48. Unless you must see something mentioned in [Spring'20 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_api_objects.htm) I wouldn't worry too much.

If your client wrote a specific class (service) to present you with data and it's written in v.48 it might not be visible when you login as v.47. But then they can just downgrade the version and all should be well. Such custom services are rarely usable by generic ETL tools anyway so it'd be a concern only if you do custom coding.

> whether the Enterprise or the Partner API is relevant for Pentaho

Sounds like your ETL tool uses SOAP API. Salesforce offers 2 versions of the WSDL file with service definitions.

"Partner" is generic, all SF orgs in the world produce same WSDL file. It doesn't contain any concrete info about tables, columns, custom services written on top of vanilla salesforce. But it does contain info how to call login() or run a "describe" that gives you all tables your user can see, what are their names, what are columns, data types... So you learn stuff at runtime. "Partner" is great when you're building a generic reusable app that can connect to any SF or you want to be dynamic (some backup tool that learns columns every day and can handle changes without problems. Or there's a "connection wizard" where you specify which tables, which columns, what mapping... new field comes in - just rerun the wizard).

"Enterprise" will be specific to this particular customer. It contains everything "Partner" has but will also have description of current state of database tables etc. So you don't have to call "describe", you already have everything on the plate. You can use this to "consume" the WSDL file, generate your Java/PHP/C# classes out of it and interact with them in your program like any other normal object instead of crafting XML messages.
The downside is that if new field or new table is added - you won't know if your program doesn't call "describes". You'd need to generate fresh WSDL and consume it again and recompile your program...

Picking right one really depends what you need to do. ETL tools I've met generally are fine with "partner".

> Is the "Web Services lookup" the right step

No idea, I've used Informatica, Azure Data Factory, Jitterbit, Talend... but no idea about this Pentaho thing. Just try it. If you pull data straight from SF tables without invoking any custom code (you can think of SF custom services like pulling data from stored procedures) - API version shouldn't matter that much. If you go < 41.0 I believe you won't see Individual object for example but I doubt you need to be on so much cutting edge.